# Github branch strategy

Tags: git

My current project is to compare compression size and decompress time for 3d meshes/floating point. This is my current branch strategy for example

```
main - best strategy will be merged here
zstd - branch for each compression type (most uses submodule)
gzip
draco
example-no-compression
```

Is there any general workflow/github commands to easily manage this type of branch strategy? Or any better strategy? I find it hard to work with a single branch with so many submodules.

Different branch uses different submodules, but this can be easily done by deleting build-cache so submodules won't conflict each build. However, main build scripts in CMakeLists is different and I'm not sure how to decouple them for each type. I also have github actions that run and build so different branch really makes it easier. perhaps I should create user input based action instead of automatic.

Comment: Can you explain more about how you're using submodules and how they complicate the issue?

Comment: By your description, a basic [feature branch workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow) should do it. *But is this a version control issue at all?* Could you support multiple compression strategies by [delegating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_(computing)) to a compression object with a [common interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern)? This potentially makes the code more flexible and robust, and avoids long running branches. And could you explain how submodules are involved?

Comment: Different branch uses different submodules, but this can be easily done by deleting build-cache so submodules won't conflict each build. However, main build scripts in CMakeLists is different and I'm not sure how to decouple them for each type. I also have github actions that run and build so different branch really makes it easier. perhaps I should create user input based action instead of automatic.

Comment: @hugo Ok, that's some detail to work with. Rather than trying to do this in the comments, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74062238/edit) and add more detail about your setup, what you're trying to achieve, and the specific problems you're having.